# Buses movement data visualization in QGIS

Tags: qgis, time, tracking, movement-data

What is the easiest way to visualize the movement of city buses in QGIS, as it is shown at this website?  https://anitagraser.com/2020/05/24/movement-data-in-gis-30-synchronized-trajectory-animations-with-qgis-temporal-controller/

There is a precise timetable for buses movement from the official site of public transport service of my city. It contains the information for each bus to bus-stop arrival time. Also I'm going to create a line layer of roads and point layer with bus-stops (I can create a point layer with points, laying on the roads near the bus-stops (using snapping options)) to show precisely places, where the buses exactly stop.

How  can I create such an animation (as at Anita Graser's website) with not very much difficulty?

Comment: Temporal Controller is coming soon on the QGIS 3.14 release.  Here is a great setup (having start_end dates/times) demo on creating temporal layers > https://youtu.be/vgDg5cRwPRw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the 'dev' version of QGIS (To be released)

The **Fields** you use to create a temporal layer need to be in DATE format (not String/Var or Numeric)

There is some basics required
here Start and End fields have been added.

Then use the Temporal option in the layer to set the start and end.

When this is completed you will get a clock in the layer - this can be clicked and the Temporal Controller will be shown.

There are few settings you will need to adjust (frame rate etc).

When your happy you can click the Export button (highlighted in red)
Which will export png files for each frame.
Then this can be converted into an animation (many tools can do this).

[image]